# How to sort an array of pointers with a pointer to NULL?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I tried to implement a bubble sort of array of pointers, from greatest to least value that they point to, basically I have to put a pointer to NULL in the middle of the elements (second cell), and when I try to sort them, I want the NULL pointer to be put to the last position of the cell (2) and the other ones to be in order except for this one that is put to the last position.
But this gives me a segmentation fault:

```
typedef struct example{
     int data;
}exp;

exp *arr[3];

static void sort_arr(exp *[]);

int main(){
 
 arr[0] = malloc(sizeof(*arr[0]));
 arr[0]->data = 1;

 arr[1] = NULL;

 arr[2] = malloc(sizeof(*arr[2]));
 arr[2]->data = 2;

 sort_arr(arr);

 return 0;
}

static void sort_arr(exp *pass_arr[]){
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 3; ++j)
        {
            if (pass_arr[i]->data < pass_arr[j]->data)
            {
                exp *temp = pass_arr[i];
                pass_arr[i] = pass_arr[j];
                pass_arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. In order to sort an array, you should establish some ordering relation, such as `<` for the `data` member. But how `NULL` element would compare to any non-NULL element? Can you define that?

Comment: using `->` on a null pointer may cause a segmentation fault. So if you intend your data to contain null pointers then you will need to modify your sort function to be able to cope with null pointers

Comment: @EugeneSh. I tried in many other ways to compare NULL pointers, because in the actual code I don't have to move just one but at least two or three pointers to NULL, there is not way I can compare them (for at least on my experience), it always crashes the program.

Comment: If you want `NULL` to be sorted at the end, you should treat is as greater than any other value. Check for this before comparing the datas.

Comment: @M.M How can I adapt the sorting algorithm to this case?

Comment: @Barmar should I allocate memory, then increase the value to its greatest, sorting to the last position, and then free the memory?

Comment: No, see how I do it in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check whether an array element is `NULL`, and treat it as lower than the other value.

```
            if (pass_arr[i] == NULL || 
                (pass_arr[j] != NULL && pass_arr[i]->data < pass_arr[j]->data))
            {
                exp *temp = pass_arr[i];
                pass_arr[i] = pass_arr[j];
                pass_arr[j] = temp;
            }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was enough, now the job works smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

Use a comparison function that is pointer-aware, something like

```
#define EQ  0
#define LT -1
#define GT +1

static int cmp( x *exp, y *exp )
{
  if ( x == NULL && y == NULL ) return EQ ; // Two NULLs compare equal
  if ( x == NULL && y != NULL ) return GT ; // NULL compares high with respect to non-NULL
  if ( x != NULL && y == NULL ) return GT ; // NULL compares high with respect to non-NULL

  // if we get here both X and Y are non-null,
  // and so can safely be de-referenced

  if ( x->data < y->data ) return LT ;
  if ( x->data > y->data ) return GT ;

  // must be equal

  return EQ; 
}
```

Your test in your sort routine changes then from

```
if ( pass_arr[i]->data < pass_arr[j]->data )
. . .
```

to

```
if ( cmp( pass_arr[i] , pass_arr[j] ) < 0 )
. . .
```

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to change the if statement for example the following way

```
if ( pass_arr[j] != NULL && 
     ( pass_arr[i] == NULL || pass_arr[i]->data < pass_arr[j]->data ) )
```

This is better than this condition

```
if (pass_arr[i] == NULL || 
    (pass_arr[j] != NULL && pass_arr[i]->data < pass_arr[j]->data))
```

because in the last case there can be redundant swaps of two null pointers.